# template parameter list for literal operator

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming, user-defined-literals

Here is my implementation of converting binary literal to decimal:

```
template<char Head, char... Tail>
constexpr int operator"" _b()
{
    if constexpr (sizeof... (Tail) == 0)
    {
        return Head - '0';
    }
    else
    {
        return (Head - '0') * (1 << sizeof...(Tail)) + operator"" _b<Tail...>();
    }
}
```

[GCC compiles happily](https://wandbox.org/permlink/n94sAxRPduektPfL),

while [Clang fails](https://godbolt.org/z/dzfV0l):

```
prog.cc:1:2: error: template parameter list for literal operator must be either 'char...' or 'typename T, T...'
        template<char Head, char... Tail>
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
prog.cc:19:27: error: no matching literal operator for call to 'operator""_b' with argument of type 'unsigned long long' or 'const char *', and no matching literal operator template
    std::cout << 110110110_b;
                      ^
```

[icc also fails](https://godbolt.org/z/CBRJyz):

```
error: a literal operator template must have a template parameter list equivalent to "<char ...>"

    constexpr int operator"" _b()

                  ^
```

[MSVC also fails:](https://godbolt.org/z/8ehXIz)

```
<source>(2): error C3686: 'operator ""_b': literal operator template must have exactly one template parameter that is a parameter pack
```

So, icc requires `char...` while clang and msvc require `typename T, T...` or `char...`, only gcc allow my `Head` and `Tail`.

The workaround should be simple ---- just replace `char Head, char... Tail` with `char... digits` and return a new `aux` function which using `char Head, char... Tail` as template parameters, or use a struct then specialize `head` and `head, tail...` without `if constexpr`.

But I didn't find related requirement from the standard draft. Can you tell me which one conforms the standard? Of course, if you have more elegant solution(besides the two I mentioned above) which will not invoke the compiler errors, please paste here, I'll very appreicate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The standard spells it out pretty explicitly in [[over.literal]/5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/over.literal#5):

> The declaration of a literal operator template shall have an empty parameter-declaration-clause and its template-parameter-list shall have a single template-parameter that is a non-type template parameter pack with element type `char`.

So GCC is wrong in allowing this.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know who's right but I propose a C++17 alternative: comma operator and template folding instead of recursion

```
   template <char ... Chs>
   constexpr int operator"" _b()
    {
      int ret {};

      return ((ret <<= 1, ret += Chs - '0'), ...);
   }
```

Comment: @陳力 - You're welcome. I find very funny template metaprogramming.

Answer (score 2):

Literal operator template of the form

```
template <class T, T... >
constexpr int operator "" _b();
```

is a clang and gcc extension, MSVC don't support that extension.

There was however a proposal to [reconsider literal operator templates](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2017/p0424r1.pdf)

Comment: P0424 was abandoned for something much better: [P0732.](https://wg21.link/P0732) It just gives you the ability to make array objects that act like literal strings (among many other things). And it's already in the working paper for C++20.